# CircuitsClouds: Why is led voltage not dropping?

Tags: voltage, led, circuit-analysis

Today I used the website http://circuits-cloud.com/ for the first time.

I created the circuit below. I assume N is the forward voltage of the LED.

- What I would expect: VoltMeter 2 equals the forward voltage of LED2 (which is N = 1.8 V).
- What I see: VoltMeter shows 0.03 V

As a side note, when I add two more LEDs, resulting in 3 times the forward voltage of 1.8 V which is 5.4 V, while the voltage source is only 5 V, VoltMeter2 still shows a value.

Do I do something stupid?

[image]

Comment: Nope, if N is the forward voltage it should show the LED forward voltage drop! Although I think the voltage source is 9V as that is between brackets besides it.

Comment: True, the voltage source is 9 V, but I would expect the VoltMeter would show the voltage drop (at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter \$N\$ is not the forward voltage. It looks like the simulator is using the Shockley diode equation, which provides the diode forward current as a function of the diode forward voltage. The parameter \$N\$ is the **ideality factor**.

If you want to properly simulate an LED you should get the model parameters from the manufacturer of the LED.

Comment: Ok, that explains; actually I didn't want to use it for an actual LED now, I was just creating some random simple example in CircuitsClouds (as part of a video electronics course I'm doing), but trying my own circuit.

Comment: This isn't enough to explain OP's result. If I build the same circuit in LTSpice with N=1.8, I get a diode forward drop of about 1.3 V. I have to increase IS to 0.01 (from the default value of 1e-14) to get close to the given result.